# OpenMP with g++ MacOS on Sierra

Tags: gcc, makefile, openmp

I have a makefile with the following that I'm trying to make on macOS Sierra:

```
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -m64 -fopenmp -O3
```

and I keep getting the error `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`.

I did

```
brew install libomp
brew install llvm
brew install gcc
```

These all were successful but I still get the same error. Would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I tried to do `clang -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -c src/mdasim.C -o obj/mdasim.o` but then its saying `fatal error: 'malloc.h' file not found`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options...

---

As you have installed **llvm** with **homebrew**, you can compile C++ code using OpenMP with:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0/bin/clang++ -fopenmp main.cpp -o main
```

---

As you have installed **GCC** with **homebrew**, you can compile C++ code using OpenMP with:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-9 -fopenmp main.cpp -o main
```

---

As you have installed **libomp**, you can use that with the Apple-supplied **clang++** (note it is not in `/usr/local` because it is supplied by Apple) to compile C++ with OpenMP with:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -I/usr/local/include -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib -lomp main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried these three solutions, though, and still got the fatal error: `fatal error: 'malloc.h' file not found`. Is this a issue with the package or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you #included "stdlib.h"? Please add your code to your question using the `edit` button.

Comment: I'm just trying to compile this software: https://github.com/hzi-bifo/mdasim.